# How to adjust the volume of MpMoviePlayerController in Iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I need a help fro your side.I am using the MPMoviePlayerController and I need to mute the volume of the movieplayer forever.Is there any property to do this.Can you please post some code regarding to this.

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Srilakshmi.

Answer (score 6):

`[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:(use a value between 0.0 and 1.0)]`

If your `MPMoviePlayerController` uses the application audio session, this should work.

Comment: It is the only way of setting the volume on MPMoviePlayerController programmatically. As I have mentioned in the post, for this to work, your movie player needs to be using the application audio session. This seems like a hack though - since I am not really USING the MPMusicPlayerController - so I wouldn't be surprised if this breaks in a future release of IOS. You're warned.

Comment: yeah, this will basically mute your device (any music playing in the background will be muted), and you will see the mute icon appear on screen when this code runs...so this works but make sure to set the volume back to a desirable level somewhere in your code.