# How to adjust Volume of movie

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using MPMoviePlayerController in my application, i am facing problem in setting volume in slider, I am pasting code for audio file, which work, please help me the exact thing for video file.

```
- (IBAction)volumeDidChange:(UISlider *)slider
{
    [_audio setVolume:[_volumeSlider value]];  //works for audio
    [_video setVolume:[_volumeSlider value]];  //doesn't works for video
}
```

*Where _audio is `AVAudioPlayer *_audio;` and _video is `MPMoviePlayerConrtoller *_video`. Both are in different application one foe video and other for audio. The AudioApp works for it, but VideoApp doesn't.

Comment: You're going to have to post more information than that. What is `_video` declared as, for example.

Comment: Assuming _video is an MPMoviePlayerController, it may not work any longer, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793839/how-to-adjust-the-volume-of-mpmovieplayercontroller-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: Nick Bull i have added more detail..........John please read again, and thanks for sharing link, but i have already visited it, it didn't help me.

Comment: Khalid, there is no `setVolume:` method in `MPMoviePlayerConrtoller`. How you are able to run the application?

Comment: Aadhira! Then can you tell me the exact method, which i can use and do work exactly same as setVolume: perform in audio file.

Answer (score 0):

With the `useApplicationAudioSession` set to `TRUE`, the movie player with use the system audio session which you can then configure using the `AVAudioSession`.

See [the following Apple doc for more info.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW1)

Here is the doc on [working with audio sessions in movie players etc.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/WorkingWithOpenALiPodMusicandMovies/WorkingWithOpenALiPodMusicandMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH14)